Proper Way to chant Gayatri Mantra
I am a Janenu Dhari Brahman, I wanted to learn the proper way of chanting Gayatri Mantra.
I have been chanting the mantra out loud since my thread ceremony but was recently told that one should only chant the mantra in mind.
Also, I have combed through multiple sources(this forum, quora, websites etc) and have found conflicting information everywhere.
The only parameter consistent throughout all sources is the ideal time for chanting is 4 am to 6 am.
I have a number of questions as follows:

Correct Posture
Should I chant it out loud or in my mind
Direction(North/ East are recommended , just confirming)
What is the involvement of pranayam in this and which one should be followed(more info about the routine would be helpful)?
Mudra
Every year we are supposed to take sankalp of chanting 'x' number of gayatri mantra everyday, I am lagging behind , is there any way to make up for the lost count over the years?

